# Display Signal Value with Other Text

Tags: elm

I'm just starting to learn Elm. In this program I would like to update the screen with the mouse coordinates and arrow key state formatted in some output.

My plan was to create a record called Input and have that set with the Signals by function input. Then showGameInputs would use the Input record to get the values and combine them with some text to return an Element to main.

```
import Mouse
import Keyboard
-- Create a record named Input
type Input = { mouseX:Int, mouseY:Int, arrowUpdown:Int, arrowLeftRight:Int }

-- Combine Signals into Input type
input: Signal Input
input = Input <~ Mouse.x ~ Mouse.y ~ lift .y Keyboard.arrows ~ lift .x Keyboard.arrows

showGameInputs: Input -> Element
showGameInputs { mouseX, mouseY, arrowUpdown, arrowLeftRight } = plainText ("asdf" ++ show mouseX)


main: Signal Element
main = showGameInputs input
```

Here is the error:

[1 of 1] Compiling Main                ( Functions.elm )
Type error on line 19, column 23 to 28:
        input

Expected Type: Signal Input
     Actual Type: Input

Very new to Elm and functional programming so I suspect I am missing something fundamental here.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. The error message is a bit confusingly formatted (a known problem), but it says the type that `input` should actually be is `Input`. The reason it says that is because you're applying `showGameInputs: Input -> Element` on `input: Signal Input`. All you need is to change `main` to:

```
main = showGameInputs <~ input
```